# How switch char* on std::string in my implementation of func?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

How convert my function from const char* to string? I need it withot templates. Just rebuild my function pattern_founder(const char*, const char*) on pattern_founder(std::string, std::string). I trying to do it with iterators, but something went wrong. Thank you.

```
 static bool pattern_founder(const char* file_path_ptr, const char* pattern) noexcept
    {
        const char* supp_file_path_ptr = nullptr;
        const char* supp_pattern = nullptr;
        while (true) 
            if (*pattern == '*') {
                supp_file_path_ptr = file_path_ptr;
                supp_pattern = ++pattern;
            }
            else if (!*file_path_ptr)
                return !*pattern;
            else if (*file_path_ptr == *pattern || *pattern == '?') {
                ++file_path_ptr;
                ++pattern;
            }
            else if (supp_file_path_ptr) {
                file_path_ptr = ++supp_file_path_ptr;
                pattern = supp_pattern;
            }
            else 
                return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what the code is meant to do?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and explain what went wrong and we will help you to make it work. But SO is no free code writing service.

Comment: @JasperKent, ok. This code is compare two C-style strings and tell us do we have pattern in file_path_ptr. Pattern is name of file or file path with special jokers. Now, I writing program like you can see in your explorer on windows, you place some line like "hello.cpp", prohramm compare all variants and give you which possible.
P.s. sry for my eng:#

Answer (score 1):

The trivial solution is to add this overload:

```
static bool pattern_founder(const std::string& file_path, const std::string& pattern) noexcept
{
   return pattern_founder(file_path.c_str(), pattern.c_str());   
}
```

If you want to only have a `std::string` version:

```
static bool pattern_founder(const std::string& file_path, const std::string& pattern_str) noexcept
{
    const char* file_path_ptr = file_path.c_str();
    const char* pattern = pattern_str.c_str();
    // Paste your existing code here.
}
```

Comment: The first variant I have now, but it is not what I want. The second variant didn't work with my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? If your existing code works, this can't go wrong. (It does exactly the same as the first, but with the `c_str()`s moved inside the function.)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to change this, is just change your function parameters into `const std::string` and start your function with declare variables that are just the c string of the original string, on which you can use the code you've already written. You can get the C string of string `s` by doing `s.c_str()`

To work with strings, you'll have to `#include <string>`. You can either convert you `char*` to a `string` by doing:

```cpp
char *cStr = "C++";
std::string Str = std::string(cStr);
```

With this, you can convert your arguments into a string. Another way to do this is just change your argument types from `const char*` into `std::string`. You'll have to adjust your code then, e.g. to check whether the first character of the pattern is an asterisk, you can check `pattern[0] == '*'`

You can assign an empty string to it in the nullptr and test for emptiness of the string.

I don't know what your trying to do, but you can also keep an index for at which char you are in the string as a seperate integer.

Comment: It isn't work. You didn't even watch on code.